# What is a good heuristic for game AI? Design for a Cat Mouse Cheese game

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am designing an AI for mouse and cat. So they have HP, and cat will chase and eat mouse, mouse will eat cheese. This eating action will help them to gain HP. If they can't eat food, they will die if they use up all the HP.

So I searched through books and I have a basic algorithm for this.

```
def chooseAction(actions, goals):
  # Go through each action, and calculate the
  # discontentment.
  bestAction =  actions[0]
  bestValue = calculateDiscontentment(actions[0], goals)
  for action in actions:
    thisValue = calculateDiscontentment(action, goals)
    if thisValue < bestValue:
      bestValue = thisValue
      bestAction = action
  # return the best action
  return bestAction

def calculateDiscontentment(action, goals):
  # Keep a running total
  discontentment = 0
  # Loop through each goal
  for goal in action:
    # Calculate the new value after the action
    newValue = goal.value + action.getGoalChange(goal)
    # Get the discontentment of this value
    discontentment += goal.getDiscontentment(value)

struct Goal:
  value
  def getDiscontentment(newValue):
    return newValue * newValue
```

This algorithm is quite easy to understand, and quite easy to implement.

So I have to determine Goal and goal value for each action they take.

Let say a mouse, He may want to move, eat.

So I have to come up with a value(wiliness) for these values.

What is a good way to determine these values?

My approach is here.

Ley say my mouse have a view range of 3 cells and it can only walk in four directions up down left and right.

The goal eat value may determine by its MAX_ENERGY and NOW_ENERGY and I come out a formula
eatValue = MAX_ENERGY - NOW_ENERGY. This make sense because, it NOW_ENERGY is equal to MAX_ENERGY, my mouse has a wiliness 0 to eat.

What is a good way of come out this simple formulations?
What will be the good heriustic for my mouse to move?

Comment: Interesting. Are there any other elements to this that you'd like to mention? Both cats and mice are somewhat social creatures. Do they have scents? Vision? Or is it a simulation consisting entirely of Pixel-Tom and Pixel-Jerry?

Comment: Haha I didn't go into that deep. Maybe mouse will reproduce when their energy reach a certain amount

Comment: They have a certain view range

Comment: Generally safety is paramount unless starving, and there should be a small desire to explore for food. Apart from that, which give you a structure with 3 goals (run, eat, search) and 4 actions (north east south west), it seems to me **heavily dependent on what aspects of the world there are**, mainly factors that determine the behavior you expect. This is too broad a question - no constraints and 'cat','mouse' are undefined. If the goal of this project is actually to have a play around, great what is the question. If there is a real goal with constraints, think carefully and clarify that now.